# My First Person Player Capsule Is Always About 6 inches Under The Floor

Tags: unity, mesh, collider, meshcollider, character-controller

Here is the problem. This is the exterior of the hallway in which my player capsule is standing. Notice the bottom of the capsule poking through the floor.
[image]

This is the interior of the hallway, notice my player capsule standing there
[image]

And this is the view from the player's fps camera
[image]

I attached a mesh collider to the hallway's interior (named `SpaceshipMain_001-FBXFile2`) so it should simply follow the fbx's visual geometry right? Also I know it's not the player's capsule collider because the player's capsule collider actually extends beyond the bottom of the player capsule.
[image]

It's worth noting that the player capsule isn't "stuck." I can walk all over the hallway, it's just that part of the capsule protrudes below the bottom of the floor. I didn't even have a chance to tag the ground level yet to complete the ground check functionality for jumping.

So why is my player capsule sinking below the floor? Is there any way that I can actually see the mesh collider for `SpaceshipMain_001-FBXFile2` in case the collider isn't actually flush with fbx's geometry?

Comment: It looks like you have more than one capsule collider here - can you show us how all of them are set up? It could also be that the character controller's center and height are being used instead of the collider's - we can't see the cylinder's settings to check whether they match what the controller says.

Comment: Is there more than 1 capsule collider? Where are you seeing that in the picture? Also yeah I can definitely show more, what part of the code should i show? Would it help if I post the player prefab and ship's fbx file?

Comment: Ohhhhh I see I accidentally added a capsule to the cylinder in addition to the parent first person GameObject. I fixed it by deleting the capsule collider on the cylinder and enlarging the capsule collider on the parent first person GameObject. I'll post a solution shortly, thanks for the help!

Comment: "Where are you seeing that in the picture?" In the last image, you can see three sets of green capsule-shaped wireframes, nested like matryoshka dolls. The outermost one is brightest, but there are two fainter ones inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally added 2 capsule colliders. I correctly added 1 to the `First Person Player` prefab object but then added a second one to `Cylinder`. I deleted the capsule collider attached to `Cylinder` and enlarged the capsule collider attached to `First Person Player` because it was way too small. The fact that it was too small caused the collision to happen several inches or maybe a foot above the bottom of the mesh in `First Person Player`